# How to get the category of a value in pandas

Tags: pandas, categories, categorical

I wonder how I query and get the the category for a given value

For example, with the following code I map the four strings to four categories

```
cat_type = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'])
```

Now I want to query and get the category for another value, something like

```
cat_for_c1 = cat_type.<somehting>('c1')
```

where as `cat_for_c1` represents the category not the string value. It seems that there is no `<something>` [according to the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html).

Is it possible otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

[get_indexer](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) could be what you are looking for:

```py
print(cat_type.categories.get_indexer(["c3"])[0])  # 2

print(cat_type.categories.get_indexer(["c5"])[0])  # -1
```